# Matlab: GUI. Get handler of ActiveX control

Tags: matlab, user-interface, activex

I download activeX component **mschrt20.ocx** and registered it.

Then i add this to GUI and see, that i don't know, how to set/get properties without handler, cause it **doesn't** have `Tag` property.

Instead of `Tag` property it have `hWnd` property.

How to get it handle, knowing `hWnd`?

Another question is alternative solution.

I can create object like this:

```
      f = figure('position',[0 0 600 500]);
      mschrt = actxcontrol('MSChart20Lib.MSChart.2',[0 0 600 500], f);
      %... many settings here
```

but for this i must to create figure and put it to gui form.

How to do it in gui? (axes, maybe?)